# OdataController query plan not optimal because of DTO mapping

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata

When mapping a DAL object to DTO object I get an unexpected query.

I have some DAL objects:

```
public class MainDalObject 
{
   public Guid Id { get; set;}
   public string Description { get; set; }
   public ICollection<SubDalObject> Subs { get; set; }
}

public class SubDalObject 
{
   public Guid Id { get; set;}
   public string Description { get; set; }
   public MainDalObject Main { get; set; }
}
```

And my DTO classes:

```
public class MainObject 
{
   public Guid Id { get; set;}
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public IEnumerable<SubObject> Subs { get; set; }
}

public class SubObject 
{
   public Guid Id { get; set;}
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public MainDalObject Main { get; set; }
}
```

My MainObject controller contains a IQueryable method:

```
public IQueryable<MainObject> Get() 
{
   return (from m in Context.Get<MainDalObject>()
    select new MainObject 
    {
       Id = m.Id,
       Name = m.Description,
       Subs = m.Subs.Select(s => new SubObject 
       {
          Id = s.Id,
          Name = s.Name
       }
    });
}
```

This works fine, however the query is not optimal. When i trigger the query on /api/MainObject , I am not selecting the subitems at all. But when i look at the query it is selecting the subItems anyway.

However when I change the query to /api/MainObject?$select=Id,Name , the query is not selecting the SubObjects.

So what I am expecting is that somewhere in the WebApi framework, when no SelectExpandFilter is used, the responsewriter is doing a ToList(), without specifying the Select statement.

I am looking for the best place to fix this problem, I could probably set a select expand ODataQueryOption that could fake an select or expand call, but I am not sure if that is the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone else runs in this problem, this is what I have done to fix it. The select expand query should be derived from the edmmodel in the request context, but this is basically how it works.

```
public virtual IQueryable<TDTO> Get(ODataQueryOptions queryOptions)
        {
            if (queryOptions.SelectExpand == null)
            {
                var selectOption = new SelectExpandQueryOption("Id,Name", string.Empty, queryOptions.Context);
                Request.SetSelectExpandClause(selectOption.SelectExpandClause);
            }

            return (from m in Context.Get<MainDalObject>()
    select new MainObject 
    {
       Id = m.Id,
       Name = m.Description,
       Subs = m.Subs.Select(s => new SubObject 
       {
          Id = s.Id,
          Name = s.Name
       }
    });
}
```